# Turning the "Autocreate conversation" setting on via API

Tags: twilio-api

I'm attaching a picture here to make it more clear about what exactly I'm trying to do. I have sub-accounts under my account for which I purchase a number and that turn on "auto create conversation" setting for each of those subaccounts.

The way I do it from the Twilio Online GUI screeen is attached in the picture. However, I'd like to automate this using API. I haven't been able to do this exactly.

The closest thing I found was here. https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/address-configuration-resource

This hasn't worked for me.

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the steps I'm doing right now

1. Create a sub-account under main account
2. Purchase a number under sub-account
3. Attach the phone number to the default messaging service using the snippet below

```js
await client.messaging.v1.services(service.sid)
    .phoneNumbers
    .create({
      phoneNumberSid: activeNumberSid
    });
```

4. Then create the addressConfiguration for this newly purchased number
   as mentioned below

> Address Configuration

```
client.conversations.v1.addressConfigurations
  .create({
     friendlyName: 'My Test Configuration',
     'autoCreation.enabled': true,
     'autoCreation.type': 'webhook',
     'autoCreation.conversationServiceSid': 'ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     'autoCreation.webhookUrl': 'https://example.com',
     'autoCreation.webhookMethod': 'POST',
     'autoCreation.webhookFilters': ['onParticipantAdded', 'onMessageAdded'],
     type: 'sms',
     address: '+37256123457'
   })
  .then(address_configuration => console.log(address_configuration.sid));
```

Here's the configuration of the default conversation service

I ran this code

```
async function _test() {
  let service = await client.conversations.v1.services('IS4faafa8...').fetch();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(service, null, 4));
}
```

to get this output (I have removed some characters from the ids for privacy reasons)

```
{
    "accountSid": null,
    "sid": "IS4faafa8.....",
    "friendlyName": "Default Conversations Service",
    "dateCreated": "2022-03-09T23:29:02.000Z",
    "dateUpdated": "2022-07-20T17:49:19.000Z",
    "url": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8.....",
    "links": {
        "users": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../Users",   
        "roles": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../Roles",   
        "participant_conversations": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../ParticipantConversations",
        "conversations": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../Conversations",
        "bindings": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../Bindings",
        "configuration": "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS4faafa8...../Configuration"
    }
}
```

Picture attached of the GUI Screen
[image]

Comment: When you say it hasn't worked, what did happen? Did you get an error? What is the result of creating an address configuration in the API like in the example in your question?

Comment: It creates the configuration but that doesn't turn on the auto conversation creation feature. I've tried sending a msg on that number after doing so and it DID NOT create conversation

Comment: What does the messaging service integration config say? Particularly under what to do with incoming messages?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Config gets created successfully. However, it still hasn't "turned on" the setting for auto-create conversation. Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: In step 3 you add the phone number to a messaging service. What is the config for the messaging service?

Comment: I don't create a new messaging service. I use the default one so I'm assuming whatever the default settings are that twilio provides? Do you want me to attach them here somehow? Screenshot or actually the JSON object of what that service looks like?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what those settings on the messaging service are, yes.

Comment: I added the default conversation service configuration and the code I used to get that in my original post. Please see that. I really appreciate you looking into this.